# What is most efficient approach to read multiple JSON files between Pandas and Pyspark?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark

I have a cloud bucket with many (around 1000) small JSON files (few KB each one). I have to read them, select some fields and store the result in a single parquet file. Since the JSON files are very small, the resulting dataframe (around 100MB) stays in memory.

I tried two ways. The first is using Pandas with a for loop:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json

path = ...
df = pd.DataFrame()
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
   for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.json'):
      with os.open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            json_file = json.loads(f.read())
            df = pd.DataFrame(json_file)
            df = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

The second option would be using Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

path = ...
spark_builder = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name).config(conf=conf)
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_builder)
df = sql_context.read.json(path)
```

What is the most efficient way to read multiple JSON files between the two approaches? And how the solutions scale if the number of files to read would be larger (more than 100K)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running Spark in a cluster, it will not change much.

Pandas dataframe is not distributed. When performing transformations on a pd dataset, the data will not be spread across the cluster so all the processing will be concentrated in one node.

Working with the Spark datasets - like in second option - Spark will send chunks of data to the available workers in your cluster so this data will be processed in parallel, making the process much more fast. Depending on the size and shape of your data, you can play with how this data is "sliced" so you can increase performance even further.

Comment: The pyspark code would run in a cluster with a serverless service, so the number of nodes and their configuration is all managed by the cloud provider. I would like to know if there would be a real benefit using Spark over the single-node solution with this number of files, and eventually how the solution would scale with more files to read.